# Add padding to button text in CSS to let background image appear

Tags: css, asp.net

I have add an asp button to my aspx page. Using CSS I added a background image as follows:

```
 .newbutton {
         background: url(../Images/add4.png);
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:18px 18px;
        border-radius: 5px;
         padding: 5em 10em 5em 25em;
        }
```

The aspx button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="BtnNewRecord" runat="server" Text="New Record"  CssClass="newbutton" >
```

The problem is that the button text overrides the background image. I used padding as in CSS above but it doesn't do any change. 
You can find the button image in the snippet below.

```html
<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=20jka4y" target="_blank"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/20jka4y.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
```

EDIT:

HTML Markup for button:

```
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$BtnNewRecord" value="New Record"  id="MainContent_BtnNewRecord" class="newbutton" />
```

EDIT #2:

I found this in Site.css :

```
 input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Could this be conflicting with my .newbutton style ? If so how can i remove this conflict ?

EDIT 3:

I tried all the solutions in the comment and the answers below, but it seems that problem is with "width: auto" in the ".button" css in Site.css. When i comment this line, the changes are taking effect, but it also messes up every other button width in my web application. 
Any Ideas how i can override the width in my ".newbutton" style?

Comment: Please update the question with the real HTML markup.

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean by html markup, can you please clarify ?

Comment: I meant the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) output of the button in the source code of the page.

Comment: Ok I've updated my question with it

Comment: No, button is <button>, is not <input> button.

Comment: @user4612290 : Do you want something like this [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekkft6rz/1/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find working demo here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekkft6rz/1/). I guess this is what you were looking for.

```
.newbutton {
            background: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/vista-general/16/add.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 18px 18px #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-position: center left 5px, center left 5px;
        }
```

Just add this in your **.newbutton** CSS. Change URL on backgroud as per your's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried this but it seems that the line "width:auto" in my ".button" class is preventing these changes from taking effect. Please check my updated question

Comment: I used this answer but I had to set the width of the asp button manually in the aspx page.

Comment: @user4612290: Welcome. Ok i will see to it what i can do more :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
background-position: left;
```

it will change the position of the image or increase the width of your button

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried this but it seems that the line "width:auto" in my ".button" class is preventing these changes from taking effect. Please check my updated question

Comment: @Suprabhat give you the solution  with background-position